# How to return scipy interval with higher precision

Tags: scipy

My confidence interval is only returned with 1 decimal place.

```
poisson.interval(0.95, 5/94.32)
(0.0, 1.0)
```

How can I increase the precision to be similar to the result in R?

```
poisson.test(5, T=94.32)$conf
0.01721254 0.12371005
```

Comment: I don't think that the issue is precision related. All of scipy.stats interval functions return "end-points of range that contain 100 * alpha % of the rv’s possible values.", see the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.interval.html). So unlike your result in R, this one is not a confidence interval for the poisson rate parameter but rather simply an interval that gives equal probability on either side of the median.